# A water circle of few radius is around the park

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, sentence, writing

In the following image:

[image]

Do you see the water in a few feet radius around a land? How do you describe this? Let's assume that the land is a park and there is no fountain. Can I express it this way:

> A water circle of few radius is around the park.

I'm not sure if that sentence is grammatically and logically correct.

Or can I say it this way:

> The park is surrounded by a circle of water having few feet radius.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might enjoy participating at our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: For the shape of the water: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39196/3306

Comment: How about, "The park is encircled by a 10-meter wide ring of fountaining water." (Not sure on the fountaining! lol!)

Comment: Your main problem here is the idea of saying *few radius*.  That makes no sense. *Radius* doesn’t take *few*; it might take *small* or *narrow*.  You use *few* when counting things, not measuring them.

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably use the word ***[moat](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moat)***.

> **moat** *noun*
>       a deep, wide ditch surrounding a castle, fort, or town, typically filled with water and intended as a defence against attack.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moat)

Modern moats would normally be decorative rather than defensive. There are a couple below. I would re-write your particular phrase as

> The park is surrounded by a circular moat a few feet wide.

[image: Decorative exterior moat]

[Black Lion](http://2blacklions.com/kalkan-property/kalkan-luxury-villas/v480/v480VillaEntrance.htm)

[image: Decorative interior moat]

[Dornob Design Ideas](http://dornob.com/water-beds-take-two-funky-liquid-furniture-ideas/#axzz2RxXLfzZr)

Comment: The (OP's) shape is known as an 'annulus' or 'circular ring'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah well there we are. I interpreted the question as what to call the feature itself rather than its shape. (It could be a circular moat).

Comment: I think that moat accurately conveys the "surrounding nature" of the feature, and also allows the OP to say "few feet wide" without needing to reference the size of the park itself. An annulus requires 2 radii to describe, or one absolute radius and a width. The original proposed statement (in the question) suggests a park which is smaller than a hot tub. Note also that while it is debatable whether "radius" is used in common speech, I would *bet money* that annulus is *virtually unknown* in common parlance.

Comment: @horatio we don't know that the audience of the OP is one that needs common parlance (they could be technical), and "moat" indicates something *surrounding*, given it's hisoric use as a defensive feature.  The OP's depicted pond is not a moat.

Answer (score -2):

"An annulus pond, 17 feet wide, borders the south-eastern edge of the park"

'17 feet' is the *radial width* of the pond (water feature), but we never speak of radius in common speech.  It is technical language for conveying specifics, like if discussing how to build a bridge over it, or how to leap across it.

Comment: I do think on SE sites that a downvote should necessitate a). a comment, or b). an upvote of an existing comment