# What do you call a cylinder with a hole down the center?

Tags: mathematics, shapes

Imagine a 3D cylinder, like a can. Now imagine that almost like an axle spot for a wheel, there's a hole shaped in a perfect circle going down the cylinder. That's the shape I have to figure out the name for. Mathematical names are preferred, but any name works!

Comment: If the bore of the hole is axial ( is that what you meant by"going down the cylinder"?), then it, too, is a cylinder.

Comment: Any hole bored through a solid is a cylinder, although it might have ends which need special description.

Comment: There's only 1D in *cylinder.*

Comment: It's basically a 2-dimensional concentric circular torus extended in a third dimension to make a hollow cylindrical solid. I don't think there's a special term (like _frustrum_ for cones) that describes this.

Comment: What about _wheel_?

Comment: Related but not the same: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39196/what-do-you-call-a-disk-with-a-hole-in-the-middle

Comment: I think you call it a "pipe".  (Well, actually, "cylinder" is the common term, unless it's exceptionally long.)

Comment: So you mean basically like a very tall doughnut?

Comment: Without further specification (e.g.: ratio of length to width, ratio of interior diameter to exterior diameter, relative location and orientation of the hole) you're likely to get a number of inaccurate or otherwise case-specific suggestions. Are you actually looking for a word to generally describe any object of this type, or do you have something a bit more particular in mind?

Comment: Tube. Thick-wall or thin-wall. If cylinder is short enough, the holed variety might be called a washer.

Comment: Really? You couldn't figure out the word tube?

Comment: A man, a worm, and a straw are topolgically equivalent.

Comment: Mitch got it right. The three-D version of http://english.stackexchange.com/a/39225/3306 is a torus. Since the OP asked for a mathematical word, the sub-discipline is called topology. Topologically speaking, it doesn't matter how thick the cylinder is or how big the hole is. It's still a torus.

Comment: You ought to fill in some of your user profile, so we can tell what context your questions generally come from.

Comment: @rajah9: That assumes OP is doing topology.  If he/she is doing geometry instead, *torus* would be completely wrong.

Comment: @NateEldredge please see this entry at Wolfram Mathematica: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html . The categorization they use is Geometry -> Solid Geometry -> Tori.

Comment: @JimReynolds I think you forgot how to spell "dcylindder" (note, the silent "d")

Comment: Sometimes "p" is silent, as in *swimming pool.* :)

Comment: There is a shape with a hole http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus torus that could be functionally the same because it also has a hole in it.

Answer (score 36):

A solid cylinder with an axial hole is still a **cylinder**. If the length of the cylinder is very much less than the diameter and the bore is small compared to the diameter it is a **washer**. If the length is much larger than the diameter, and especially if the bore is nearly as large as the cylinder diameter it is a **tube**.

Comment: I think "washer" is only likely to be properly recognized in mechanical contexts, and may be especially misleading or inappropriate for some others.

Comment: "washer" is used in mathematical contexts for integration of certain types of functions.

Comment: True: I might say "like a washer" rather than describing it *as* a washer.

Comment: A cylinder with `length < diameter` is still a cylinder.

Comment: Yes,but if length << diameter it's also a washer.

Comment: And if it's longer/taller it's an *extruded washer*.

Answer (score 14):

In technical terms, it seems that the three dimensional object would be called an *[annular cylinder](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020722588900791)*:

> A problem in generalized thermoelasticity for an infinitely long
>   ***annular cylinder***

[Annulus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/annulus) is certainly a [two-dimensional object in geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) describing one cross section of an **open cylinder**:

> NOUN
>
> technical
>
> 1 A ring-shaped object, structure, or region.

A ***[barrel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/barrel)*** is also a common less technical reference for a bored cylinder:

> A cylindrical tube forming part of an object such as a gun or a pen:

***Tube***, ***pipe*** and ***ring*** also offer less technical descriptions.

---

International Journal of Engineering Science Volume 26, Issue 3, 1988, Pages 301–306

www.oxforddictionaries.com

en.wikipedia.org

Comment: Annulus appears to be 2D...

Comment: Though mathematically similar, an annulus is considered very flat (like a washer) or even 2D. Much of any depth to it and people wouldn't call it an annulus anymore. I don't have a good single word for what is desired but a 'cylinder with bored/rifled center'.

Comment: As the other comments mention, an annulus is 2-dimensional; this object is an _annular cylinder_.

Comment: I recall encountering some writing by a non-native speaker that used *annulus*. That's unheard of in American English and I suggested *ring* for that particular use.

Comment: @jdlugosz: In technical mathematical writing, *annulus* is the recognized term for the 2-dimensional shape, partly because *ring* is used in mathematics for something [completely different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 14):

[Cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29) -Wiki

**Open Cylinder**

A cylinder -with the generating lines perpendicular to the bases, with its ends closed to form two circular surfaces- with a hole perpendicular to its base, is a **right circular, open cylinder**.
Its function tells us if it's a pipe, washer, bearing, beer can, ect.

Google's 4th picture hit for *open cylinder*:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is mistaken. An _open cylinder_ is a surface, not a 3D solid, and the image is wrong or at the very least, highly misleading. See details in [my answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615399/20364).

Answer (score 13):

Colloquially, i'd just call it a hollow cylinder.

Comment: Not just colloquially. Whenever this shape appears in physics, it's called a [hollow cylinder](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=physics%20hollow%20cylinder).

Comment: If I read the phrase "hollow cylinder", I'd be wondering if it had end-caps or not.

Comment: … not to be confused with a foolish Dutchman.

Comment: But wouldn't it be weird to call a cylinder with a 12cm diameter "hollow" if it had only a 1mm axial center-bore?

Answer (score 7):

I've always considered that a Toroid

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid

Comment: "toroid" is a bit too vague. It is like calling a square a quadrilateral.

Comment: You can call it a "rectangular toroid" to specify the shape of its cross section.

Comment: No, it would be a circular toroid. The premodifier to toroid describes the cross section, not the projected profile.

Answer (score 4):

Stealing from other answers as well.

- Tube (if it's longer than it is wide)
- Tunnel (if it's a tube big enough to crawl or drive through)
- Pipe (if it's long and fixed in place)
- Hose or Conduit (if it bends)
- Ring or Disc or Washer (if it's shorter than it is wide)
- Straw (if you drink through it)
- Bucket (if it has a cover on one end)
- Bottle (if it's a bucket with the open end narrower than the closed end)
- Can or Canister or Capsule (if it has a cover on both ends)
- Duct (if it has junctions)
- Barrel (if you shoot projectiles through it, or it's made of compressed wood planks, or it's a canister big enough to store a person)
- Toroid (if its ends meet)
- Sleeve (if it's designed to snugly surround something)
- Coil or Solenoid (if it's made by tightly winding material around a cylinder)
- Bushing (if it has internal, inverse screw threading)

Answer (score 3):

In the UK Steel Industry it is referred to as a Hollow Bar

Answer (score 1):

In French, it would be called "un manchon". I found the following translations for this word: muff, sleave, bush(ing), socket. I don't know which one is the most appropriate.

Comment: I think within an engineering context, [bushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_bearing#Bushing) and [sleeve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeve_(disambiguation)) are reasonable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

- Tube
- Ring
- Pipe
- Washer
- Straw
- Hollow cylinder
- Cylindrical shell
- Bored cylinder

Or, perhaps the most technical name for it:

- Long round thing with a hole through it

Answer (score 1):

It's called a **tube** - a hollow cylinder. E.g.; gun barrels are sometimes called metal tubes; plastic sewer pipes get addressed as tubes; and architects get the privilege to call tunnels tube-shaped structures.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematics, the shape the OP describes is a [*cylindrical shell*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cylindrical%20shell), which is a 3D solid more colloquially called a "tube" or "pipe" or some of the other terms @wberry listed.

The term "cylinder" itself [is now quite ambiguous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4817839/29642), referring both to a 3D solid in some contexts and the surface area of such a solid in other contexts. Where it refers to a surface area, the surface area includes the areas of the disks at either end. The term [*open cylinder*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=open%20cylinder) refers to the surface area of just the sides of the solid, without the end disks. An open cylinder is ***not*** a 3D solid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I remember using in geometry class: "coaxial cylinders". Pipe is correct too.  Disclaiming that the hole is not implied there. [This question is very close to yours, check it out.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39196/what-do-you-call-a-disk-with-a-hole-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, *prism* is used to describe a 2D object projected along a third axis to form a 3D object. As long as the bores are coaxial and concentric, call it a *annular prism*. If the third axis is perpendicular to the 2D plane, it is a *right annular prism*. This will work in any technical context where you want a generalized term for this concept.

However, once you have a specific context or example, *annular prism* becomes unwieldly, and I'd just call any specific one of these a cylinder.

So if you want to talk about automating FEA grid optimization for these forms, *annular prism* is the way to go. But when it comes time for the machinist to make one, they make you a cylinder.

Note,  toroidal prism is a type of polyhedron - it's an easy mistake to make.

You also want to make sure there aren't any ideas of light refraction attached.

related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837256/what-do-you-call-a-3d-annulus-cylindrical-shell-and-parts-of-it

"Free vibration analysis of bi-directional functionally graded annular plates using finite annular prism methods"

When light refraction is the central idea, *don't* use annular prism - use prism rod (lead with the word prism when talking about light refraction) - https://www.swiftglass.com/portfolios/prism-rods.